# How can I adjust the background color of the native Android buttons to be compatible with the BottomNavigationBar background?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm creating an app in Flutter and I would like the background color of the native Android buttons to be the same background color as the BottomNavigationBar widget, in a similar way to how the Play Store achieves it, this is my example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class HomeScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Home'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_filled,
              size: 40,
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_filled,
              size: 40,
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

And this is how I would like it to be: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the system navigation bar color. You can place it in the `main()` function.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: /* Your NavigationBar Color */,
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: /* Your NavigationBar Color */,
  ),
);
```

Comment: It is also possible to set `SystemUiOverlayStyle` in the `systemOverlayStyle` property of the `AppBar`